# libtorchvision.so does not exist

Tags: c++, cmake, torchvision

I am new to cmake. I am configuring cmake for torchvision. When I gave path to TorchVisionConfig.cmake, I got the following error:

```
set_target_properties Can not find target to add properties to:
  TorchVision::TorchVision
```

So, I coppied TorchVisionTargets.cmake and TorchVisionTargets-release.cmake from CMakeFiles/Export/Share/cmake/TorchVision to the build folder containing TorchVisionConfig.cmake.

Now I am getting following error:

```
CMake Error at /path/libtorch/share/cmake/TorchVision/vision/build/TorchVisionTargets.cmake:70 (message):
The imported target "TorchVision::TorchVision" references the file

     "path/libtorch/share/cmake/lib/libtorchvision.so"

  but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

  * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and contained
```

TorchVisionTargets.cmake and TorchVisionTargets-release.cmake are generated by cmake only. Following is the code:
TorchVisionTargets.cmake:

```
# Generated by CMake

if("${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}" LESS 2.5)
   message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake >= 2.6.0 required")
endif()
cmake_policy(PUSH)
cmake_policy(VERSION 2.6)
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file.
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Protect against multiple inclusion, which would fail when already imported targets are added once more.
set(_targetsDefined)
set(_targetsNotDefined)
set(_expectedTargets)
foreach(_expectedTarget TorchVision::TorchVision)
  list(APPEND _expectedTargets ${_expectedTarget})
  if(NOT TARGET ${_expectedTarget})
    list(APPEND _targetsNotDefined ${_expectedTarget})
  endif()
  if(TARGET ${_expectedTarget})
    list(APPEND _targetsDefined ${_expectedTarget})
  endif()
endforeach()
if("${_targetsDefined}" STREQUAL "${_expectedTargets}")
  unset(_targetsDefined)
  unset(_targetsNotDefined)
  unset(_expectedTargets)
  set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
  cmake_policy(POP)
  return()
endif()
if(NOT "${_targetsDefined}" STREQUAL "")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Some (but not all) targets in this export set were already defined.\nTargets Defined: ${_targetsDefined}\nTargets not yet defined: ${_targetsNotDefined}\n")
endif()
unset(_targetsDefined)
unset(_targetsNotDefined)
unset(_expectedTargets)


# Compute the installation prefix relative to this file.
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
if(_IMPORT_PREFIX STREQUAL "/")
  set(_IMPORT_PREFIX "")
endif()

# Create imported target TorchVision::TorchVision
add_library(TorchVision::TorchVision SHARED IMPORTED)

# Load information for each installed configuration.
get_filename_component(_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
file(GLOB CONFIG_FILES "${_DIR}/TorchVisionTargets-*.cmake")
foreach(f ${CONFIG_FILES})
  include(${f})
endforeach()

# Cleanup temporary variables.
set(_IMPORT_PREFIX)

# Loop over all imported files and verify that they actually exist
foreach(target ${_IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS} )
  foreach(file ${_IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_${target}} )
    if(NOT EXISTS "${file}" )
      message(FATAL_ERROR "The imported target \"${target}\" references the file
   \"${file}\"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}\"
but not all the files it references.
")
    endif()
  endforeach()
  unset(_IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_${target})
endforeach()
unset(_IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS)

# This file does not depend on other imported targets which have
# been exported from the same project but in a separate export set.

# Commands beyond this point should not need to know the version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
cmake_policy(POP)
```

TorchVisionTargets-release.cmake:

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file for configuration "Release".
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Import target "TorchVision::TorchVision" for configuration "Release"
set_property(TARGET TorchVision::TorchVision APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS RELEASE)
set_target_properties(TorchVision::TorchVision PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LINK_DEPENDENT_LIBRARIES_RELEASE "torch;Python3::Python"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libtorchvision.so"
  IMPORTED_SONAME_RELEASE "libtorchvision.so"
  )

list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS TorchVision::TorchVision )
list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_TorchVision::TorchVision "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/lib/libtorchvision.so" )

# Commands beyond this point should not need to know the version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
```

How should I get libtorchvision.so file? I am working on non-GPU machine.

Comment: "So, I coppied TorchVisionTargets.cmake and TorchVisionTargets-release.cmake from ..." - No these files are not intended to be copied from somewhere. You need to **install** torch on your machine and point CMake to the installation directory.

Comment: I had installed torchvision and given path to cmake. After that I was getting the error that target is not found. TorchVisionTargets.cmake file was generated by cmake only but in sub folder CMakeFiles. When I copied these files to build folder, that error was gone but I encountered the above error.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to deploy detectron2 models using torchscript. When configuring cmake for it, I am getting the above errros. I have downloaded libtorch where shared libraries for all other dependencies have been provided. But for torchvision, I am not able to get kibtorchvisio.so file.